# PyLint Class Error

Tags: python-2.7, pylint

In pylint on python 2.7 I'm getting the following error:

```
common/cdn/edgecast/EdgeCast.py:14: [E0239(inherit-non-class), EdgeCast] Inheriting 'Base', which is not a class.
```

The following is the relevant code from EdgeCast and Base:

`EdgeCast.py`

```
from common.cdn import Base


class EdgeCast(Base):
    """
    Class comment
    """
    def __init__(self, account, db_conn=None):
        super(EdgeCast, self).__init__(account, db_conn=db_conn)
```

`Base.py`

```
class Base(object):
    """
    Class comment
    """
    def __init__(self, account, db_conn=None):
        pass
```

Can anyone point me to what would be causing PyLint to see `Base` as not a class?

Comment: Are you sure they're the same `Base`? What's in `common.cdn`?

Comment: Just figured out that the problem was the `__init__.py` file was importing the Base class file but not importing the Base class so the import in EdgeCast was using the Base module and not the class.

Comment: @Nalum you should probably write that as an answer :)